# How to collect channels hierarchically?

Tags: nextflow

How can I run a process with one instance for each pair of values in two lists, then collect the output of those instances along only one of the lists at a time?

For example, if you run this Nextflow script:

```
numbers = Channel
    .from(1..2)
    .into{numbers1; numbers2}

letters = Channel
    .from('A'..'B')

process p1 {
    input:
    each number from numbers1
    each letter from letters

    output:
    path "${number}${letter}.txt" into foo

    """
    echo "$number $letter" > ${number}${letter}.txt
    """
}

process p2 {
    input:
    path numberletters from foo.collect()
    each number from numbers2

    """
    for file in $numberletters; do
        cat \$file >> $baseDir/${number}.out
    done
    """
}
```

you get two output files (as expected): `1.out` and `2.out`. Each of these contains the same set of lines:

```
1 A
1 B
2 A
2 B
```

**How can I make it so that `1.out` contains only `1 A` and `1 B`, and `2.out` contains only `2 A` and `2 B`?** i.e., `.collect()`ing the `foo` channel only collects the `p1` outputs according to their `letter` input and keeps separate instances with different `number` inputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to have your first process output a tuple which includes the 'number' as the first element, and then call [groupTuple()](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#grouptuple) to group together the files that share the same key:

```
numbers = Channel.of(1..2)
letters = Channel.of('A'..'B')


process p1 {

    input:
    tuple val(number), val(letter) from numbers.combine(letters)

    output:
    tuple val(number), path("${number}${letter}.txt") into foo

    """
    echo "${number} ${letter}" > "${number}${letter}.txt"
    """
}

process p2 {

    publishDir baseDir, mode: 'copy'

    input:
    tuple val(number), path(numberletters) from foo.groupTuple()

    output:
    path "${number}.out"

    """
    cat $numberletters > "${number}.out"
    """
}
```

If you know how many elements to expect in each group, you can set the 'size' attribute to allow the groupTuple operator to stream the collected values as soon as possible.